# Google analytics pageviews per profile

Tags: google-analytics-api

I'm using Google analytics api to get the pageviews for some sites in the last month.

```
  $startDate = '2018-01-23';
  $endDate = '2018-02-23';
  $metrics="ga:sessions,ga:pageviews";
```

However for example site x.com I have multiple profiles.

profile1 with 112233 pages view.
profile2 with 223344 pages view.

Should I consider the site x.com had 112233+223344 views in the last month or how do I correctly interpret the pageviews when multiple profiles ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

1. I think you need to name one of the trackers.
2. Setup a cross-site domain and add reporting filters to compare the traffic between the two and the left-overs will be the unique item for each tracker.

References:

https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1032400?hl=en

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/creating-trackers#working_with_multiple_trackers

https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1034342?hl=en